# Windows 11 Keyboard & Mouse Only Working During Boot

Tags: windows, windows-11

*Please let me hear any ideas. I really don't want to redo this system*

I have a family member with a Lenovo desktop that recently received a Windows 11 update that has caused the keyboard and mouse to not have any response to input except on the BIOS and Windows Recovery Environment.

I've tried:

1. Uninstalling quality updates with Windows Recovering Environment.
2. Restoring to the oldest available point (should be before the
   offending updates) with Windows Recovering Environment.
3. Booting into safe mode which still doesn't respond to keyboard or
   mouse input
4. The machine has Teamviewer. I can connect and see the prompt to
   accept the connection appear but have no way to accept it. The
   password to Teamviewer is unknown. It seems Teamviewer was not
   logged into an account on this machine.
5. NoMachine is also installed. It was believed that the software was
   set to autostart with login. This machine has not been discovered
   from other clients however.

I'm looking and reaching for any ideas before I either reset the operating system or backup and reinstall the OS. Maybe I can use PUTTY to launch a remote terminal and try to start NoMachine? Or use a remote terminal to do something else ...maybe install different drivers?

I spend most of my time on Linux, Ubuntu particularly. This reminds me why

Comment: Honestly is sounds like the Windows installation is corrupt and should simply be reinstalled.